# Sahi automation tool issue

Tags: java, ssl, https, sahi

I am working with the sahi web automation tool.Recently i am facing one issue. i am testing https web site,during the ssl certificate acceptance process where install certificate button is not        coming.if i add the respective site in trusted sites list then the install certificate button is coming.If we install the certificate , at the playback time it is getting completely stucked. Though it is a pure sahi issue still if any one can put some possible solutionn for that.it will be really helpful.

Thanks in dvance 
Qrious13

Comment: Which Sahi version and which browser is creating this problem. It will be helpful if you can mention the Java version also.

Comment: The version of sahi is open source 4.3
The browser we have taken is ie8 and 9.

Comment: have you been through this: http://sahi.co.in/w/https-ssl

The first part is about Sahi Pro, so you need to follow the steps for open source mentioned at the bottom of the page.